# Query MySQL for data that appears more than once, but only if another field differs

Tags: mysql

I apologize in advance, I don't even really know how to properly word this question, so I'll just describe the scenario:

I have a database with rows that contain several pieces of data, lets say for example there is "PHONE", "ADDRESS" and "NAME" columns.

I'd like to be able to run a query that looks for instances of "NAME" appearing more than once (duplicates), but only if the "PHONE" AND "ADDRESS" field doesn't match.

If the NAME entry is a duplicate of another row, and PHONE OR(!) ADDRESS also matches, I'm not interested.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for names that have different phones or address:

```
select name
from table t
group by name
having min(phone) <> max(phone) or
       min(address) <> max(address);
```

If you want to require that both are different, then use `and` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to do a self JOIN and then check on those conditions, depending on what you want the `OR` below might be an `AND` too, try it and see.

```
SELECT T1.NAME,T1.PHONE,T1.ADDRESS,T2.NAME as NAME2,T2.PHONE as PHONE2,T2.ADDRESS as ADDRESS2
FROM yourTable T1 INNER JOIN yourTable T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME AND (T1.PHONE > T2.PHONE OR T1.ADDRESS > T2.ADDRESS)
```